# How to partially initialize an ArrayVec?

Tags: syntax, rust, initialization

I need structures with fixed maximum size, so the obvious choice seem to be [arrayvec crate](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.4.8/arrayvec/). However, I'm stuck when `ArrayVec` is a member of a structure that later needs to be partially initialised:

```
use arrayvec::ArrayVec; // 0.4.7

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    member_one: Option<u32>,
    member_two: ArrayVec<[u16; 5]>,
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut test = Test {
        member_one: Some(45678),
        member_two: [1, 2, 3], // <- What to do here to initialise only 3 elements?
    };

    print!("{:?}", test);
}
```

I'd like to initialise the first three elements of the `ArrayVec` as it's perfectly capable of holding any number of elements from zero to 5 (in my example), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collect into an `ArrayVec` from an iterator:

```
let mut test = Test {
    member_one: Some(45678),
    member_two: [1, 2, 3].into_iter().collect(),
};
```

Comment: Looks like serious shortage in ArrayVec, but your suggestion would do.

Comment: Great, works like a charm - saves me a lot of headache! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayVec` does not offer a one-step method to do this. Instead, create the `ArrayVec` and then add values to it, in any of the ways you can add values:

```
let mut member_two = ArrayVec::new();
member_two.extend([1, 2, 3].iter().cloned());
let test = Test {
    member_one: Some(45678),
    member_two, 
};
```